# How many onto functions satisfy the following property.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ A= \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \} $ consider functions $f:A \to A$ that are onto how many of these functions satisfy that for all even x. $f(x) \neq x$

Firstly i notice that a is finite so this is a bijective map if it is onto implying that this is a permutation on 10 symbols so there are 10! unique functions. now i now i need to perform a Derangement of all the even numbers in the set while doing what i please with the odd numbers.

What i would really like to do is consider all of the derangement's  then divide it by 2 and subtract the number from n! but im not sure that would actually be the right number.

Comment: Did you mean $A=\{1\ldots 10\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can count them using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as we do for derangements, but we restrict to the even numbers:

- Include $9!$ permutations.
- Exclude $\binom{4}{1} 8!$ permutations which map at least one even number to itself.
- Include $\binom{4}{2} 7!$ permutations which map at least two even numbers to themselves.
- Exclude $\binom{4}{3} 6!$ permutations which map at least three even numbers to themselves.
- Include $\binom{4}{4} 5!$ permutations which map all four even numbers to themselves.

Thus, Inclusion-Exclusion gives $$9!-\binom{4}{1} 8!+\binom{4}{2} 7!-\binom{4}{3} 6!+\binom{4}{4} 5!=229080.$$

This number can be verified using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code

```
Number(SymmetricGroup(9),alpha->ForAll([2,4,6,8],i->i^alpha<>i));
```

which returns `229080`, or we could even generate them all using

```
Filtered(SymmetricGroup(9),alpha->ForAll([2,4,6,8],i->i^alpha<>i));
```